# Share a service instance between multiple microfrontends in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have a project in which I created 2 angular microfrontends that use module federation.
For simplicity I will call them mfe1 and mfe2.

The mfe1 inside it opens the mfe2 always by module federation.

I have a custom angular library that exposes a service, I would like this service to have only one instance shared between mfe1 and mfe2.

It's possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module Federation Shared Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501315/module-federation-shared-services)